# check all files in fileset contain a string in ant

Tags: ant

Can anyone provide an example of an ant build which checks if all files found by a fileset contain some token and do not contain some other token?

(google has not been very useful with this, so here I am...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be done using ant's `resourcecontains` condition, but I'm not sure it accept multiple resources (see [the docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) for details). However, it can be done using `resourcecount` contition:

```
<project name="Test" default="main" basedir=".">

  <patternset id="filestotest">
    <include name="*.c"/>
  </patternset>

  <target name="main">
    <condition property="contain">
      <resourcecount when="greater" count="0">
        <fileset dir=".">
          <patternset refid="filestotest"/>
          <contains text="main" casesensitive="yes"/>
        </fileset>
      </resourcecount>
    </condition>
    <condition property="donotcontain">
      <isfalse value="${contain}"/>
    </condition>
    <echo message="${contain}"/>
    <echo message="${donotcontain}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

You can use `<resourcecount when="equal" count="0">` to test for the opposite condition for another token.